# se puede agregar un scrollbar horizontal a un listbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

estoy programando en asp.net y mi problema es que al llenar un listbox con registros de una BD no se ven completos por su gran tamaño, trate de hacer mas grande el control pero por algunna razon no se hace mas grande de 280. Me podrian ayudar para hacer mas grande el control o para ponerle un scroll si es que se puede.

Answer (score 0):

podrias aplicar esta tecnica

[How to show horizontal ScrollBar in a ListBox in asp.net](https://asp-net-example.blogspot.com.ar/2013/12/aspnet-listbox-horizontal-scrollbar.html)

[Add horizontal scroll to asp.net listbox control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45545/add-horizontal-scroll-to-asp-net-listbox-control)

veras como el listbox se define dentro de un div para habilitar el scroll.

si defines el `overflow:auto;` en el div aparecer los scroll si el listbox supera las dimensiones

Tambien habria que analizar como asignas el Width del listbox,porque entiendo que este deberia poder definir un valor mayor al que indicas como limite.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">        
<head id="Head1">        
    <style type="text/css">
        .block { 
            display:inline-block;
            vertical-align:top;
            overflow-x:scroll;
            overflow-y:hidden;
            border:solid grey 1px;
            width:200px;
        }
        .block select { 
            padding:10px; 
            margin:-5px -20px -5px -5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>        
<body>        
    <form id="form1" >        
    <div>        
        
        <div class="block">  
         <select multiple>
         <option>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</option>
            <option>bbbbbbbb</option>
            <option >cccccc</option>
            <option >ddddddddd</option>
         </select> 
        </div>
    </div>        
    </form>        
</body>        
</html>
```

Comment: gracias por responder. El tamaño se lo he asignado de varias formas.

Comment: desde css, desde la ventana de propiedades y manualmente arrastrando la orilla del control. Cuando lepongo un tamaño mas grande en la parte de diseño de visual si se ve el cambio pero al ejecutar la pagina el control no aumenta de tamaño.

Comment: es que no tienes que poner ningun tamaño a la lista, deja que los mismso datos sean los que definan cuanto es el ancho

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "scrollY":        "200px",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "paging":         false
    } );
} );
```

```css
table.dataTable{width:100%;margin:0 auto;clear:both;border-collapse:separate;border-spacing:0}table.dataTable thead th,table.dataTable tfoot th{font-weight:bold}table.dataTable thead th,table.dataTable thead td{padding:10px 18px;border-bottom:1px solid #111}table.dataTable thead th:active,table.dataTable thead td:active{outline:none}table.dataTable tfoot th,table.dataTable tfoot td{padding:10px 18px 6px 18px;border-top:1px solid #111}table.dataTable thead .sorting,table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc,table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc{cursor:pointer;*cursor:hand}table.dataTable thead .sorting,table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc,table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc,table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled,table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled{background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center right}table.dataTable thead .sorting{background-image:url("../images/sort_both.png")}table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc{background-image:url("../images/sort_asc.png")}table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc{background-image:url("../images/sort_desc.png")}table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled{background-image:url("../images/sort_asc_disabled.png")}table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled{background-image:url("../images/sort_desc_disabled.png")}table.dataTable tbody tr{background-color:#ffffff}table.dataTable tbody tr.selected{background-color:#B0BED9}table.dataTable tbody th,table.dataTable tbody td{padding:8px 10px}table.dataTable.row-border tbody th,table.dataTable.row-border tbody td,table.dataTable.display tbody th,table.dataTable.display tbody td{border-top:1px solid #ddd}table.dataTable.row-border tbody tr:first-child th,table.dataTable.row-border tbody tr:first-child td,table.dataTable.display tbody tr:first-child th,table.dataTable.display tbody tr:first-child td{border-top:none}table.dataTable.cell-border tbody th,table.dataTable.cell-border tbody td{border-top:1px solid #ddd;border-right:1px solid #ddd}table.dataTable.cell-border tbody tr th:first-child,table.dataTable.cell-border tbody tr td:first-child{border-left:1px solid #ddd}table.dataTable.cell-border tbody tr:first-child th,table.dataTable.cell-border tbody tr:first-child td{border-top:none}table.dataTable.stripe tbody tr.odd,table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd{background-color:#f9f9f9}table.dataTable.stripe tbody tr.odd.selected,table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd.selected{background-color:#acbad4}table.dataTable.hover tbody tr:hover,table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover{background-color:#f6f6f6}table.dataTable.hover tbody tr:hover.selected,table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover.selected{background-color:#aab7d1}table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr>.sorting_1,table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr>.sorting_2,table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr>.sorting_3,table.dataTable.display tbody tr>.sorting_1,table.dataTable.display tbody tr>.sorting_2,table.dataTable.display tbody tr>.sorting_3{background-color:#fafafa}table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr.selected>.sorting_1,table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr.selected>.sorting_2,table.dataTable.order-column tbody tr.selected>.sorting_3,table.dataTable.display tbody tr.selected>.sorting_1,table.dataTable.display tbody tr.selected>.sorting_2,table.dataTable.display tbody tr.selected>.sorting_3{background-color:#acbad5}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd>.sorting_1,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.odd>.sorting_1{background-color:#f1f1f1}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd>.sorting_2,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.odd>.sorting_2{background-color:#f3f3f3}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd>.sorting_3,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.odd>.sorting_3{background-color:whitesmoke}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd.selected>.sorting_1,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.odd.selected>.sorting_1{background-color:#a6b4cd}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd.selected>.sorting_2,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.odd.selected>.sorting_2{background-color:#a8b5cf}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd.selected>.sorting_3,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.odd.selected>.sorting_3{background-color:#a9b7d1}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even>.sorting_1,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.even>.sorting_1{background-color:#fafafa}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even>.sorting_2,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.even>.sorting_2{background-color:#fcfcfc}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even>.sorting_3,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.even>.sorting_3{background-color:#fefefe}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even.selected>.sorting_1,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.even.selected>.sorting_1{background-color:#acbad5}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even.selected>.sorting_2,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.even.selected>.sorting_2{background-color:#aebcd6}table.dataTable.display tbody tr.even.selected>.sorting_3,table.dataTable.order-column.stripe tbody tr.even.selected>.sorting_3{background-color:#afbdd8}table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover>.sorting_1,table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr:hover>.sorting_1{background-color:#eaeaea}table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover>.sorting_2,table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr:hover>.sorting_2{background-color:#ececec}table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover>.sorting_3,table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr:hover>.sorting_3{background-color:#efefef}table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover.selected>.sorting_1,table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr:hover.selected>.sorting_1{background-color:#a2aec7}table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover.selected>.sorting_2,table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr:hover.selected>.sorting_2{background-color:#a3b0c9}table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover.selected>.sorting_3,table.dataTable.order-column.hover tbody tr:hover.selected>.sorting_3{background-color:#a5b2cb}table.dataTable.no-footer{border-bottom:1px solid #111}table.dataTable.nowrap th,table.dataTable.nowrap td{white-space:nowrap}table.dataTable.compact thead th,table.dataTable.compact thead td{padding:4px 17px 4px 4px}table.dataTable.compact tfoot th,table.dataTable.compact tfoot td{padding:4px}table.dataTable.compact tbody th,table.dataTable.compact tbody td{padding:4px}table.dataTable th.dt-left,table.dataTable td.dt-left{text-align:left}table.dataTable th.dt-center,table.dataTable td.dt-center,table.dataTable td.dataTables_empty{text-align:center}table.dataTable th.dt-right,table.dataTable td.dt-right{text-align:right}table.dataTable th.dt-justify,table.dataTable td.dt-justify{text-align:justify}table.dataTable th.dt-nowrap,table.dataTable td.dt-nowrap{white-space:nowrap}table.dataTable thead th.dt-head-left,table.dataTable thead td.dt-head-left,table.dataTable tfoot th.dt-head-left,table.dataTable tfoot td.dt-head-left{text-align:left}table.dataTable thead th.dt-head-center,table.dataTable thead td.dt-head-center,table.dataTable tfoot th.dt-head-center,table.dataTable tfoot td.dt-head-center{text-align:center}table.dataTable thead th.dt-head-right,table.dataTable thead td.dt-head-right,table.dataTable tfoot th.dt-head-right,table.dataTable tfoot td.dt-head-right{text-align:right}table.dataTable thead th.dt-head-justify,table.dataTable thead td.dt-head-justify,table.dataTable tfoot th.dt-head-justify,table.dataTable tfoot td.dt-head-justify{text-align:justify}table.dataTable thead th.dt-head-nowrap,table.dataTable thead td.dt-head-nowrap,table.dataTable tfoot th.dt-head-nowrap,table.dataTable tfoot td.dt-head-nowrap{white-space:nowrap}table.dataTable tbody th.dt-body-left,table.dataTable tbody td.dt-body-left{text-align:left}table.dataTable tbody th.dt-body-center,table.dataTable tbody td.dt-body-center{text-align:center}table.dataTable tbody th.dt-body-right,table.dataTable tbody td.dt-body-right{text-align:right}table.dataTable tbody th.dt-body-justify,table.dataTable tbody td.dt-body-justify{text-align:justify}table.dataTable tbody th.dt-body-nowrap,table.dataTable tbody td.dt-body-nowrap{white-space:nowrap}table.dataTable,table.dataTable th,table.dataTable td{-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box}.dataTables_wrapper{position:relative;clear:both;*zoom:1;zoom:1}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length{float:left}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter{float:right;text-align:right}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter input{margin-left:0.5em}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info{clear:both;float:left;padding-top:0.755em}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate{float:right;text-align:right;padding-top:0.25em}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button{box-sizing:border-box;display:inline-block;min-width:1.5em;padding:0.5em 1em;margin-left:2px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none !important;cursor:pointer;*cursor:hand;color:#333 !important;border:1px solid transparent;border-radius:2px}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current:hover{color:#333 !important;border:1px solid #979797;background-color:white;background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fff), color-stop(100%, #dcdcdc));background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #dcdcdc 100%);background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #dcdcdc 100%);background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #dcdcdc 100%);background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #dcdcdc 100%);background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #dcdcdc 100%)}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.disabled,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.disabled:hover,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.disabled:active{cursor:default;color:#666 !important;border:1px solid transparent;background:transparent;box-shadow:none}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button:hover{color:white !important;border:1px solid #111;background-color:#585858;background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #585858), color-stop(100%, #111));background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #585858 0%, #111 100%);background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #585858 0%, #111 100%);background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #585858 0%, #111 100%);background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #585858 0%, #111 100%);background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #585858 0%, #111 100%)}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button:active{outline:none;background-color:#2b2b2b;background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #2b2b2b), color-stop(100%, #0c0c0c));background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2b2b2b 0%, #0c0c0c 100%);background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #2b2b2b 0%, #0c0c0c 100%);background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #2b2b2b 0%, #0c0c0c 100%);background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #2b2b2b 0%, #0c0c0c 100%);background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #2b2b2b 0%, #0c0c0c 100%);box-shadow:inset 0 0 3px #111}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .ellipsis{padding:0 1em}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_processing{position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;width:100%;height:40px;margin-left:-50%;margin-top:-25px;padding-top:20px;text-align:center;font-size:1.2em;background-color:white;background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(25%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9)), color-stop(75%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255,255,255,0)));background:-webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 25%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 75%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);background:-moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 25%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 75%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);background:-ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 25%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 75%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);background:-o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 25%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 75%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 25%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 75%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%)}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_processing,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate{color:#333}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll{clear:both}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll div.dataTables_scrollBody{*margin-top:-1px;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll div.dataTables_scrollBody th,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll div.dataTables_scrollBody td{vertical-align:middle}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll div.dataTables_scrollBody th>div.dataTables_sizing,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll div.dataTables_scrollBody td>div.dataTables_sizing{height:0;overflow:hidden;margin:0 !important;padding:0 !important}.dataTables_wrapper.no-footer .dataTables_scrollBody{border-bottom:1px solid #111}.dataTables_wrapper.no-footer div.dataTables_scrollHead table,.dataTables_wrapper.no-footer div.dataTables_scrollBody table{border-bottom:none}.dataTables_wrapper:after{visibility:hidden;display:block;content:"";clear:both;height:0}@media screen and (max-width: 767px){.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate{float:none;text-align:center}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate{margin-top:0.5em}}@media screen and (max-width: 640px){.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter{float:none;text-align:center}.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter{margin-top:0.5em}}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012/10/13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dai Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>2012/09/26</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2011/09/03</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>2009/06/25</td>
                <td>$675,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2011/12/12</td>
                <td>$106,450</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2010/09/20</td>
                <td>$85,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/10/09</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>2010/12/22</td>
                <td>$92,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2010/11/14</td>
                <td>$357,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2011/06/07</td>
                <td>$206,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fiona Green</td>
                <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>2010/03/11</td>
                <td>$850,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shou Itou</td>
                <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>2011/08/14</td>
                <td>$163,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michelle House</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2011/06/02</td>
                <td>$95,400</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Suki Burks</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>53</td>
                <td>2009/10/22</td>
                <td>$114,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                <td>Technical Author</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/05/07</td>
                <td>$145,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                <td>Team Leader</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2008/10/26</td>
                <td>$235,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/03/09</td>
                <td>$324,050</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unity Butler</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/12/09</td>
                <td>$85,675</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/12/16</td>
                <td>$164,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                <td>Secretary</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2010/02/12</td>
                <td>$109,850</td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>2011/06/27</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/01/25</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: pero la pregunta plantea un scroll horizontal sobre un listbox, no un scroll verticar sobre un grid